# captions in own div outside of slider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using the  [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/). It works very well for me, but I have 1 problem. I want the captions outside of the bxwrapper.

The html of the slider looks like this only the div captions is created by me

```
            <div class="captions"></div>
            <ul class="bxslider">
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="headline, text" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="text" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="text" /></li>
            </ul>
```

The captions are generated out of the title from the images with this code:

```
* Appends image captions to the DOM
     */
    var appendCaptions = function(){
        // cycle through each child
        slider.children.each(function(index){
            // get the image title attribute
            var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');
            // append the caption
            if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {
                $(this).append('<div class="bxcaptions"><span>' + title + '</span></div>');
            }
        });
    }
```

i tried to style the captions that they are outside of the slider, but the slider uses overflow hidden and so its impossible.

So i want that the captions are written into the `<div class="captions"></div>` which i can position the way i want it.

Further i maybe want that the headline before the ,  is highlighted with h1 and the rest is normal but thats just additional.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ikokex/3

jquery:

```
var captionText = '';    
$('ul.bxslider > li > img').each(function(i,e) {
  var titleAttr = $(this).attr('title');
  if(typeof titleAttr != 'undefined') {
     var captionSplit = titleAttr.split(',');
     $('.captions').append('<div class="caption-'+i+'"></div>');
     if (captionSplit.length > 1) {
       captionText += '<h1>'+captionSplit[0]+'</h1>';
       captionText += '<span>'+captionSplit[1]+'</span>';
     } else {
       captionText += '<span>'+captionSplit[0]+'</span>';
     }
     $('.caption-'+i).html(captionText);
     captionText = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: notice that this script doesnt support more then one comma "," in the title tag of the image. you need to expand the script for this case.

Comment: sry for my late respond! i tried it but it seems to influence the function of the slider and it does not work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a solution but its very dirty! i insert this code `$('.captions').html(slider.children.eq(slider.active.index).find('img:first').attr('title'));`

at the end of the slide function in the jquery.bxslider.js line 1188.

if somebody has a better solution please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this.
below snippet is better solution for bx slider caption  outside

```js
jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: 'next',
  prevText: 'prev',
  pager: true,
  prependtxt: 'Examples  ',
  pagerType: 'short',
  mode: 'fade',
  auto: true,
  onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex) {
    $(".slider-txt").html($('.bxslider li').eq(currentIndex).find("img").attr("title"));
  },
  onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    $(".slider-txt").html($slideElement.find("img").attr("title"));
  }
});
```

```css
.slider-txt{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

<div class="image-slider">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Letterhead" title="Letterhead" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Business Card" title="Business Card" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Compliment Slip" title="Compliment Slip" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Envelope" title="Envelope" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Folder" title="Folder" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Referral Card" title="Referral Card" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Single Sided Referral Pad" title="Single Sided Referral Pad" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Post, note or thank you card" title="Post, note or thank you card" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="WEBSITE (OPTIONAL)" title="WEBSITE (OPTIONAL)" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="outside"><span id="slider-prev"></span><span id="slider-next"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-txt"></div>
</div>
```