# Trouble getting image title form bxslider to display in own div outside of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

Ok so I am having some issue with BXSlider. It's a great tool but I am trying to get the image title to display in a separate div as I don't like the way the slider transitions the captions and want to keep the caption hovered above the slider and update the div's contents accordingly.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       auto: true,
       autoControls: false,
       pager: false,
       startSlide: 0,
       onSliderLoad: function (currentSlide) {
          $("#slidercaption").empty();
          $("#slidercaption").append($('.bxslider').children().eq(currentSlide).find('img:first').attr('title'));
       },
       onSlideAfter: function (totalSlides, currentSlide) {
          $("#slidercaption").empty();
          $("#slidercaption").append($('.bxslider').children().eq(currentSlide - 1).find('img').attr('title'));
       }
   });
});
```

I have also tried the amendment to jquery.bxslider.js as suggested in [captions in own div outside of slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489553/captions-in-own-div-outside-of-slider) but this does not render the caption on the first load like in my code above.

Here is the HTML for the slider:

```
<div id="sliderHome">
    <ul class="bxslider">                    
        <li><img id="0" src="http://placehold.it/1024x350" title="Slide 1" /></li>
        <li><img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/1024x350" title="Slide 2" /></li>
        <li><img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/1024x350" title="Slide 3" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I have a div that floats above the slider:

```
<div id="slidercaption"></div>
```

The issue I am having is that it is displaying the incorrect title for the images and I'm sure it is down to the bx-clone slides but can't find a way to stop the clones.

Any help on this would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

Your right that the `clones` are throwing off your `onSliderLoad` function..  But the Index does line up with the id you have set to each image.

Here is how I would it it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       auto: true,
       autoControls: false,
       pager: false,
       startSlide: 0,
       onSliderLoad: function (currentSlide) {          
           $('#slidercaption').html($('#'+currentSlide).attr('title')); 
       },
       onSlideAfter: function (currentSlide) {
           $('#slidercaption').html(currentSlide.find('img').attr('title'));
       }
   });
});
```

**Update**

```
onSliderLoad: function (currentSlide) {          
    $('#slidercaption').html($('.bxslider li img:last').attr('title')); 
}
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/vgJ9X/17/

Comment: Only the onSlideAfter works. The onSliderLoad part doesn't give a caption. Can't figure out why...

Comment: @KB it should work..  At least in this example it does http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/15/ .. Something must be different with your html.  Do you have `ID's` set on your images?

Comment: you're right, missed the ID's on the images there. Great work, thanks alot! Still one question though. Is it possible to do without the image ID's?

Comment: Sure, instead of selecting the `onSliderLoad` title by id you can select the last slider image title.  Which seems to be a clone of the first image.  It works at least in the following case: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/vgJ9X/17/  Hopefully that same pattern will stay true for all instances of bxslider I think it would though.

Comment: @KB see my comment above.  Thanks

Comment: @Trevor sorry for the late reply. I actually developed a custom bxslider running 2 sliders and calling from 1 slider to the other.